# QDir & QFileInfo Problem

Tags: qt, qt4

Hi
I want to write a program to do this :
1 - give a path from user
2 - store whole of address of files that are in the path in the QStringList
3 - show these files in the command prompt

In fact this program is very similar to dir command : give a path and show address of whole files in that path.
I thought this program is very simple but I can't write this program with QDir and QFileInfo.
please help me.
thanks

Comment: Could you post the code which you have tried?

Comment: Could you explain us what is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: What is the question? If you want other people to write it for you. You are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation for [QDir::entryList](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdir.html#entryList) (or alternately, [QDir::entryInfoList](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdir.html#entryInfoList)).  These member functions will provide you with the names or QFileInfo objects "for all the files and directories in the directory."